# Trying capture video to read frame by frame with OpenCV on MAC, but my ".avi" file has been encoded as mpeg4

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ffmpeg

I am able to read an avi file encoded as mjpeg, but I can't succeed when the case for encoding is mpeg4 unfortunately. Any help from you would be really helpful and be appreciated. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
 ret, frame = cap.read()
 if ret:
      frame=cv2.resize(frame(img_rows,img_cols),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)         
      gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      frames.append(gray)
      cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

install the following library for ubuntu/raspbian
`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

or if you are a centos user then install the following library
`sudo yum install ffmpeg`